# Send message to a defined number of Android devices

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I am creating an Android app for a local restaurant with Unity (for augmented reality), I want to send promo messages to only some Android devices where the app is installed (randomly or other way). I want to use a PHP/MySQL web page to do that.

Comment: What do you have so far?

Answer (score 0):

With the push notification (Firebase for Android )
For notify multiple user, you can use a php server who send the notification action to firebase
https://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

Comment: Thank you. The method shown in the link is very useful but is it possible to use it in Unity with C# (no java)?